# Inheritance not only between parent->child, furthermore between all childs of a prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, prototype

i thought inheritance of objects works only from parent to childs, but my code shows a strange inheritance between "siblings".
So i wonder, why all the objects of my array *testObj* (which are childs of *myObj*) have the same data.
My code is only for learning with no specific purpose.

```
// my prototype-obj
const myObj = {
    myArray: [],
    declaration: ""
}

// my array of objects
let testObj = [];

// fill my object
for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    testObj[i] = Object.create(myObj);
    testObj[i].myArray.push("content of array " + i);        
}

// print my data
testObj.forEach((eleA,idxA) => {
    console.log("\nobj number "+idxA);        
    eleA.myArray.forEach((eleB,idxB) => {
        console.log(eleB);
    });
});
```

```
console output:

obj number 0
content of array 0
content of array 1
content of array 2

obj number 1
content of array 0
content of array 1
content of array 2

obj number 2
content of array 0
content of array 1
content of array 2
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tkzw2fn8/

Answer (score 4):

You have an object (A) where one of its properties has an array as a value.

You use `Object.create` to create some new objects (AA, AB, AC) using A as their prototype.

For each of AA, AB, AC, you access the `myArray` property and use `push` to manipulate it.

Since AA, AB, and AC don't have their **own** `myArray` property, when you access it, *the prototype chain is followed* and you get the `myArray` from A.

---

In short: Prototypal inheritance does not create deep *copies* of the inherited values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is going to take a long answer but bare with me,
When you inherit an Array "myArray" through the prototype chain, you are getting a reference, thats why its updating everywhere even if you do something like

```
console.log(myObj.myArray);
```

at the end you will see that its equal to the rest of the objects you have, now the real confusing part comes here, if you try to modify declaration inside the for loop as well,

```
testObj[i].declaration="test"+i;
```

You will notice a different behavior and thats because JS does something called "Shadowing" properties, but that only applied to primitive types, thats why when an array is changed it changes everywhere aka "inherited by reference, and a primitive type like "declaration" is not.

So in order for you to get a unique array for each object, you have to recreate that array "if and only if you have that array up the prototype chain because it will be inherited by reference if you dont", to change the reference.

hope this clears some of the confusion